# In Lyx, how can I type special characters in ERT boxes?

Tags: lyx, keyboard

I have a Czech keyboard and cannot type `čšžěů` characters in ERT boxes.
How can I make it possible to do so?
The way I currently work around this issue is by copying `čšžěů` into ERT boxes and removing those I don't need.

Comment: May this link: http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LinguistLyX be useful?

Comment: @AlanMunn You're right. I've misinterpreted it as issue inserting those special characters into LaTeX.

Comment: I am on elementaryOS linux.

Comment: Investigating a little further LyX seems to be too smart for its own good. If I switch to a Czech keyboard it doesn't allow me to enter those characters even though it allowed me to enter e.g. Icelandic characters with an Icelandic keyboard.  As you report, cut and paste works.

Comment: This is a reported, but unfixed bug as far as I can tell: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10069

Comment: Ah, thanks for investigating. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'll add an answer explaining a bit more what the problem is, since it doesn't look like this will be fixed soon, and I'm sure you're not the only person who has encountered the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in LyX (see discussion here: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9012).

The main issue is the following: LyX strives to create valid output always, since it is a  WYSIWYG (or as the LyX people say WYSIWYM) editor. Because of this, it makes assumptions about the font and input encoding for the document and prevents the user from entering characters which will be unencodable.

In the regular editor mode, the editor is aware of the encoding chosen for the document, and so any characters can be entered (e.g. if you choose to use system fonts with XeTeX/LuaTeX) but for the ERT input the input is treated as verbatim, the input is restricted to Latin1 encoded characters, which is why your Czech characters are disallowed.

For the moment your cut and paste workaround is the only real solution to the problem.