# error: uncodable character

Tags: pdftex, unicode

I tried to use subscript 2 within `\texorpdstring` for the TOC of PDF files in LyX, but I always get an error message. However, the same code works in LaTeX (TeXworks) -- (MWE below & screenshot)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
unicode=true}
\begin{document}

\subsection{\texorpdfstring{CO\textsubscript{2}}{CO<LyX Warning: 
uncodable character '₂'>}
other text}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is the warning message supposed to be pasted into your document source? When I delete that, I cannot reproduce your bug on TeX Live 2020.

Comment: It worked for me in PDFLaTeX, but compiling in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX might fix it on your installation. I’d recommend switching from 8-bit font encodings to `fontspec` if you can. This is just one of many problems they cause.

Comment: lyx is trying to protect you from entering a char it thinks your document can not handle (but this is wrong here, as in bookmarks it will work). You probably will have to find some ERT work-around to fool it. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355843/2388

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how/why it works but in this specific case using `\texttwoinferior` in the part for the PDF file does the job.